# Creating the two column design of a scientific paper

Tags: libreoffice

I want to create a document similar to the format of the following paper:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84207818/Neural-network-based-PHY-layer-key-exchange-for-wireless-communications.pdf

The above format is the design of a scientific paper, thus are there any guides or ways to create a document with a similar design? In TeX, libreoffice or anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decide to go with LaTeX, you can get pre-made templates [for conference proceedings](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html) and [IEEE transactions (journals)](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html) from the IEEE website. They also have Microsoft Word 2003 'templates' there (really just doc files) which should work to some extent in LibreOffice, at least to provide a basic format you can start with.

Everyone will have their own favorite TeX/LaTeX environment - personally I'm using TeXmaker at the moment (which you can find in the repository). To use the IEEE templates you will probably also need to install the `texlive-fonts-recommended` package.

Comment: They are (or at least the one that I'm currently using is) distributed under the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL) - see http://latex-project.org/lppl/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible in LibreOffice Writer by using [sections](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Insert_Section) (Insert -> Section).

Comment: Just for your information: Most scientific papers are written using LaTeX [citation needed] and journals often supply premade LaTeX style files which should be used when writing papers for them. Therefore, although it's a lot of work, it might be worth to learn LaTeX instead of using LibreOffice to write scientific papers.

Comment: I'd just google "LaTeX tutorial" (and make sure safe search is on, for Latex might lead to, well, distracting results ^^). Installation is rather easy, just get the texlive-generic-recommended package for starting `sudo apt-get install latex-generic-recommended`). You can add additional LaTeX packages later when needed. I wouldn't go for texlive-full, since it requires a huge amount of disk space... For editing, Lyx is a rather nice tool, though many purists will telly you that vim or emacs are the only LaTeX editors worth using ;-)